# Keras Fully-Connected Dense Output M x N?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am looking at the examples/image_orc.py [example](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/image_ocr.py) in Keras, when I run it I see something like

```
_______________
max2 (MaxPooling2D)              (None, 32, 16, 16)    0           conv2[0][0]                      
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
reshape (Reshape)                (None, 32, 256)       0           max2[0][0]                       
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense1 (Dense)                   (None, 32, 32)        8224        reshape[0][0]                    
_____________________________________________________________________________________
```

The Dense layer outputs a tensor 32x32. I am trying to replicate this in pur TensorFlow where `tf.matmul` would be used, but how can I output 32x32 using `matmul`?

Addition:

I am not trying to replicate the Keras example exactly,

```
w = 128; h = 64
# junk image, only one
dataset = np.zeros((1,w,h,1))

import tensorflow as tf

pool_size = 1
num_filters = 16

def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, w, h, 1])

W_conv1 = weight_variable([3, 3, 1, num_filters])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([num_filters])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(inputs, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

W_conv2 = weight_variable([3, 3, num_filters, num_filters])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([num_filters])
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 32, 256])

W_fc1 = weight_variable([256, 32])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([32])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

print inputs.shape
with tf.Session() as sess:
     sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
     output = sess.run(h_pool2_flat, feed_dict={inputs: dataset})
     print 'output',output.shape
```

And I get

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'MatMul_5' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,32,256], [256,32].
```

A smaller example

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

dataset = np.zeros((3,2,4))

inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2, 4])
print inputs
W = tf.zeros((4,5))
print W
W2 = tf.matmul(inputs, W)

with tf.Session() as sess:
     sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
     output = sess.run(W2, feed_dict={inputs: dataset})
     print 'output',output.shape
```

This also gives similar error

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'MatMul_12' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,2,4], [4,5].
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

That 32 is there because it was in the previous layer. It keeps unchanged.

The `tf.matmul` multiplies considering the two last dimensions, as stated [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul). (See the examples taking more than two dimensions)

I see you've got a `Dense(32)` there, with input size = 256.

This means that the weights matrix is `(256,32)`. In keras, the multiplication [as seen here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/core.py#L731) is `inputs x kernel`.

So, if you have the `input` tensor shaped as `(?, any, 256)`, and the `weights` matrix shaped as `(256,32)`, all you need is:

```
output = tf.matmul(input,weights)
```

This will output a shape `(?, any, 32)` - `any` is there untouched because it just was there before.

You may also want to sum the biases, which will follow the same principle. You need a bias vector of shape `(32,)`.

Comment: I now have dimension match as you mentioned, and am also following Keras dimensions, but now getting some kind of rank error.

Comment: Maybe I can't use >2D for tensors with matmul? If that's the case I'd have to flatten tensors to 2D before I compute the fully connected layer..

Comment: It's a possibility... although the documentation for that function clearly shows 3D examples. Maybe both vectors must be 3D. I'd probably expand the first dimension of the small matrix (making two 3D matrices) and repeat the elements in the first axis until both have the same number of first elements.

Comment: Ok... BTW, when I changed the fully connected implementation to W_fc1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(h_pool2_flat, 32) it worked. I am also going to look into fully_connected code and see what it is doing..

Comment: Aha - layers.py fully_connected says "Note: that if `inputs` have a rank greater than 2, then `inputs` is flattened prior to the initial matrix multiply by `weights`."